# MySQL: combining 2 JOINS

Tags: mysql, join

Having a problem combining 2 JOINS.  Both statements below work. I have also included the relevant fields in the 2 DBs.  My question is: 
1) How do I combine the 2 statements into 1 statement?
2) How do I reference the rows in my php to distinguish if the result was from the mmpreID JOIN or the mmparID JOIN?

Thanks

```
DB: matchmaker
mmpreID
mmparID

DB: users
uID
ufname
ulname

SELECT matchmaker.mmpreID, matchmaker.mmparID, users.uID, users.ufname, users.ulname 
FROM matchmaker 
LEFT JOIN users ON matchmaker.mmparID = users.uID

SELECT matchmaker.mmpreID, matchmaker.mmparID, users.uID, users.ufname, users.ulname 
FROM matchmaker 
LEFT JOIN users ON matchmaker.mmpreID = users.uID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT m.mmpreID, m.mmparID, u.uID, u.ufname, u.ulname,
    case 
        when m.mmparID = u.uID then 'mmparID'
        when m.mmpreID = u.uID then 'mmpreID'
        else null 
    end as Source
FROM matchmaker m
LEFT JOIN users u ON m.mmparID = u.uID or m.mmpreID = u.uID
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT m.mmpreID, m.mmparID,
    upar.uID as upar_UID, 
    upar.ufname as upar_UFNAME, 
    upar.ulname as upar_ULNAME,
    upre.uID as upre_UID, 
    upre.ufname as upre_UFNAME, 
    upre.ulname as upre_ULNAME
FROM matchmaker m
LEFT JOIN users upar ON m.mmparID = upar.uID 
LEFT JOIN users upre ON m.mmpreID = upre.uID
```

Comment: supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: OK, working now, but the results seem to be alternating. See what I am hoping to achieve below:

ROW: ufname,ulname (that match parID) | ufname,ulname (that match preID)

Comment: Would be better if you provide DDL for your schema and some `INSERT` statements for data. Then provide the desired output in full.

Comment: ufname (and ulname) should appear twice in each row, but only because there is one mmparID and one mmpreID for each row.   See below for simple example:

USERS DB columns: uID, ufname (ex: 1, John, 2 Mike).  matchmaker DB columns: mmparID, mmpreID (ex: 1, 2).  I want to show 'John' and 'Mike' in the same row in my results.

Comment: supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: @user1041931: Fixed. You really should learn how to debug simple SQL syntax errors, especially when you do not provide DDL.

Answer (score -1):

Add UNION and another column to see where it came from

```
SELECT matchmaker.mmpreID, matchmaker.mmparID, users.uID, 
users.ufname, users.ulname, "mmpar only" as source
FROM matchmaker 
LEFT JOIN users ON matchmaker.mmparID = users.uID AND matchmaker.mmparID != matchmaker.mmpreID 

UNION

SELECT matchmaker.mmpreID, matchmaker.mmparID, users.uID, 
users.ufname, users.ulname, "mmpre only" as source
FROM matchmaker 
LEFT JOIN users ON matchmaker.mmpreID = users.uID
AND matchmaker.mmparID != matchmaker.mmpreID 

UNION

SELECT matchmaker.mmpreID, matchmaker.mmparID, users.uID, 
users.ufname, users.ulname, "both" as source
FROM matchmaker 
LEFT JOIN users ON matchmaker.mmpreID = users.uID  AND matchmaker.mmparID = matchmaker.mmpreID
```

Revised the answer above to include 3 possible outcomes
1. uID only matches mmparID
2. uID only matches mmpreID
3. uID matches both mmparID and mmpreID

Yes, UNIONS are not very efficient but they are necessary at times

Comment: This works, but I am not sure how to reference the results in php? FOR example, when I output $row['ufname'], how dod I know which SELECT statement it is referencing?

Comment: @garvey, 1 select is certainly better than 2. The question wasn't which one is better :) To see where it came from, check result_type column when you're parsing your results

Comment: Sorry, can you give an example of what you mean?  Currently, the results seem to be alternating between the 2 SELECT statements.  Each row will have a ufname and ulname from both select statements.

Comment: when you're looping through in php, you can check $row['result_type'] (or maybe I shouldve called it source like @Redfilter). If it's 'query1' it's match from 1st. if it's query 2, it's match from second. You can certainly get the same row twice if mmparID and mmpreID both math uID